# Design a child control of a derived Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a custom `Panel` with another `Panel` in it. I would like to drop controls into that second Panel in design mode. I tried fixing up MSDN's example from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sycctd1z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  (using `ControlDesigner`) and set up the `GetHitTest` method to get when the cursor is over the child control.

But what now? How can I actually do anything with the child Panel?

Comment: What do you mean by "do anything with the child Panel"?  What sort of things do you want to do?

Comment: @AnnL. Drop a Control on it. (as mentioned in the question.) Resize it. etc.

Comment: What happens when you try to drop a control on it - is the control added to the parent Panel instead?

Comment: @AnnL. Even worse. It lands on the Form itself.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you very much. That looks like exactly what I was looking for. Checking it out now.